# PHP update query using IF

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to run an update query with an if statement on a MySQL database using PHP.
I would like to update the stock in my eshop, but only if the quantity that customer order exists.
I tried something like this

```
$updatequery = "UPDATE products 
                SET stock 
                CASE WHEN (stock >= '$quantity') THEN (stock=stock-'$quantity')
                    ELSE (stock= stock)
                END
                WHERE product='$product'"; `
```

or like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET\n"
. "stock = IF(stock>=$quantity, stock=stock-$quantity, IF(stock<=$quantity, stock=stock) )\n"
. "WHERE product=$product"; `
```

Is there anyone that could help me with the issue I'm having?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can't return expression like `stock = stock` from your `CASE` . Try the following :

```
$sql = "UPDATE products 
        SET stock = CASE
                        WHEN stock >= $quantity THEN (stock - $quantity)
                        ELSE stock 
                    END
        WHERE product = '$product' "
```

***or***

```
$sql = "UPDATE products 
        SET stock = IF(stock >= $quantity, (stock - $quantity), stock)
        WHERE product = '$product' "
```

Comment: +1 . . . But the single quotes around "quantity" are superfluous (because it should be a number).